# Querying Camera Params for Android Camera2 in Real-Time

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm writing an application in which I'd like to retrieve the real-time values of various camera parameters (ie. ISO, shutter speed, aperture, but most importantly ISO). I am using the Android camera2 (and eventually camera1) API's.

I've found some links on stack overflow on retrieving those values for camera1 (though that functionality itself has limited support) and have looked through camera2 documentation, but haven't found a way to get those values (most importantly ISO) in real time. Any instructions on how to retrieve these values in real time/examples of such would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On devices that support camera status output, those values are all available via [CaptureResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html), which is produced for each frame via [onCaptureCompleted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html#onCaptureCompleted(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult)).

All devices that support the [READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_READ_SENSOR_SETTINGS) capability will have the necessary values present, such as [SENSOR_SENSITIVITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#SENSOR_SENSITIVITY).